# MonoTouch upload to iOS device problem

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mono, xamarin.ios

Whenever I try uploading to a device from MonoTouch, I get the following console output and error:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -installdev="/Users/Chris/Documents/Monotouch Projects/UITextFieldTest/UITextFieldTest/bin/iPhone/Debug/UITextFieldTest.app"
Please ensure your device is connected...
Connected to: OAI
Initializing file service...
Uploading application
Finalizing file service...
Connected to: OAI
Installing application

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at MonoTouch.Installation.Installer.InstallApplication (object,System.EventArgs) <0x001b6>
at MonoTouch.Installation.Device.NotificationCallback (MonoTouch.Installation.Device/am_device_notification_callback_info&) <0x0006e>
at (wrapper native-to-managed) MonoTouch.Installation.Device.NotificationCallback (MonoTouch.Installation.Device/am_device_notification_callback_info&) <0x0003d>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.CoreFoundation.CFRunLoop.CFRunLoopRun () <0x00003>
at MonoTouch.CoreFoundation.CFRunLoop.Run () <0x0000d>
at MonoTouch.Installation.Installer.InstallApplication (string) <0x00151>
at MTouch.Main (string[]) <0x032d1>

The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

I have tried numerous projects, some of which are examples directly from the WROX and MonoTouch websites. All run flawlessly in the simulator, and compile perfectly. However, when I try to upload or run them on my device I always get that same error.

I have a valid App Developer license loaded, as well as a MonoTouch Student license. I am able to create and run applications on my device through Xcode 3.2 without any problems.

Any ideas on what is causing this problem ,and how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it ended up being the solution name containing spaces. Remove these and it should work.

Alternatively, make sure you have the right provisioning profile set up.

Comment: I do not have any spaces in the solution name. I have also tried deleting the provisioning info and reinstalling through XCode, but it still didn't work. Is this one of those 'catch all' errors that get outputted for any of a million different problems?

Comment: @Chris, not 100% sure but I've had that error for both scenarios above.

Comment: It turns out that the MonoDevelop directory was inside of a different directory that had a space in it. After removing the space, it worked alright. Apparently, no files or folders on your computer should have any spaces in them if you want to program with MonoTouch

Comment: @Chris, glad you got it sorted mate :) MonoTouch is a bit sensitive

Comment: This will be fixed in the next release of MOnoTouch (4.1). Please take the time to fill bug reports if you find such issues :-)